# What are some online (La)TeX compilers

Tags: discussion

I am delighted to see the online LaTeX compilers, such as:

- https://www.writelatex.com/
- https://www.sharelatex.com/

Is there a discussion of using these these for [Minimal Working Examples](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

I noted that WriteLaTeX was [discussed](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3164/link-to-online-latex-compiler/3167#3167) a couple years ago.

Does Tex.SE have a policy of referring users to one of these? Should it?

Comment: We have a question on the main site about this: [Compiling documents online](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3/2693).

Comment: @AlanMunn: Well, that's a much better question than mine. :) I have no objection to moderators closing this, given the link you've posted, Alan.

Comment: @BrianMHunt Unless you want to change the question to focus more on the idea of referring users.  What do you have in mind? Typically people need to debug problems with whatever distribution they have on their machine, so I'm not sure what you have in mind with this.

Comment: Thanks @AlanMunn. It's a good question. I'm not sure offhand how to improve this (though I think there might be room), so perhaps it could be made into a wikified question?

Comment: I guess you're already aware of [Link to Online LaTeX Complier](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3164/link-to-online-latex-compiler/3167#3167)... why not discuss there?

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps with the recent announcement about the [integration of CircuitLabs into Electronics SX](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/embedding-a-schematic-editor?from=CircuitLab), now's a good time to reopen the debate around linking to an online LaTeX compiler?

(Original topic here: [Link to online LaTeX compiler](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3164/link-to-online-latex-compiler/3167#3167) )

I'm one of the developers of [writeLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com), and we'd be happy to discuss the possibilities for this with the SX devs - the original answer by Stefan in the link above generated a fair amount of upvotes. We could always enable the link for an evaluation period and let the community vote on whether to keep it?

(PS: For an example of such links in operation on a forum, see the [LaTeX-Community.org announcement](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=22340) when it was integrated there in January, or the [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/weblog/2013/jan/30/online-compiler-tikz/) site which has similar functionality for the examples there)

Comment: texample.net recently started to link each TikZ example to writeLaTeX; it works pretty well.