# Is the idea of linking to an online compiler dead?

Tags: feature-request

There was a question about linking from the code examples at tex.stackexchange.com to an online LaTeX compiler about a year ago: [Link to online LaTeX compiler](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3164/link-to-online-latex-compiler). The answers and comments to the question indicate that there is willingness from several of the online compilers to help support and/or implement such a feature.

Personally, I think the feature would be great and I am therefore wondering if there is a good reason why the suggestion has not been implemented as it seemed that everyone liked the proposal and competent people offered to help.

Comment: you can paste the URL of the compiler space say with sharelatex or writelatex. Is that not the idea?

Comment: Implementation of any automated link from 'our' end would require action by the StackExchange staff/devs: not something 'we' can achieve.

Comment: I wouldn't like TeX.SX to be too reliant on a third-party online compiler. What would happen to all the code if that online compiler shut down, further down the road?

Comment: @Jubobs: I'm not suggesting that TEX.SX should rely on an external compiler. I just think replying to questions and being able to test a MWE by following a link from a code blok to an external online compiler would improve the usability of the site. I am for example using an iPad and copy/paste of LaTeX code is cumbersome. It would help a lot if code in an answer/question could be opened in the editor of one of the online compilers.